# Combining Different Attribute Selector in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is is possible to do something like this in Jquery?

```
$("a[data-tooltip-content*!='Public')")    - not containing any substring of "Public"
```

intended code:

```
$("a[data-tooltip-content!*='Public'][data-tooltip-content!*='Only Me'][data-tooltip-content!*='friends']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr,._2tdc").css({"background-color": "violet"});
$("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr,._2tdc").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
$("a[data-tooltip-content*='Only Me']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr,._2tdc").css({"background-color": "lime"});
$("a[data-tooltip-content*='friends']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr,._2tdc").css({"background-color": "cyan"});
```

1st line: if *("Public","Only Me","friends")* are not found, set colour to *"Violet"*

Comment: Have you tried? And, if you do, make sure the selector you write is valid (the one you've shown isn't);

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it?? i have tried it but it's not working!!

Comment: i have just tried to recode it again, this selector is definitely valid because i am able to invoke css background colour to 'Facebook Statuses' except the first line of code (violet), and i have tried console.log between the first line of code, and it appears that the programme will stopped running after i runs the differentmultiple attribute selector

Comment: The selector is definitely NOT valid. There is something wrong with it... You are missing the closing square bracket.

Comment: And the closing quote mark. Although I'm amazed that works at all, given the `!*=` syntax.

Comment: Here is your new best friend: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: sorry, i didn't realized i actually cropped out the codes here "

$("a[data-tooltip-content*!='Public')")    - not containing any substring of "Public"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably not with multiple attribute selectors, but with the `not` selector (which doesn't exists).

You can't use the `!` for "not contains", however you **can** use the `:not([class*="Public"])`.

Here is a working example (is just a css example, but works exactly the same with jQuery's css selectors:

```css
div {
  background: red;
}
div:not([class*="asd"]) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">123</div>
<div class="dsa">456</div>
<div class="">789</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help!!! :)
can i get an opinion in changing the title of this post to a better title to prevent misleading of question?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of jQuery's [:not()-Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("a:not([data*='Public'])");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `:not()`

```
$('a:not([data-tooltip-content*="public"])')
```

Select all `<a>` tags that *do not* contain a data attribute that contains `post`

```css
$('a:not([data-tooltip-content*="public"])').css('background-color', '#f00')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-tooltip-content="public">a link</a>
<a href="#" data-tooltip-content="private">another link</a>
<a href="#" data-tooltip-content="help me">aaaaanother link</a>
<a href="#" data-tooltip-content="public thingy">abbbnother link</a>
```